# When and Why did this website almost completely die? Did I miss something?

Tags: discussion

I've been gone a while, but I've poked my head in a few times in the last 6 months and noticed the number of questions answered has dropped DRAMATICALLY. The number of questions that even get a comment has dropped dramatically.

Did I miss something? It also seems like this has happened over a number of SE sites. 
Did everyone move to some other website?

Comment: You had not really participated in the community since you accepted an answer in September 2019.

Comment: @Ramhound how exactly is that relevant? I was never very active to begin with. It's fun answering easy questions, but I do have a real job and family to tend to. So... Did everyone quit this website? Did they move to reddit or something?

Comment: Well I answered about 20 questions every month this year, reviewed hundreds of questions this month, so I certainly don’t believe everyone quit the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users with enough reputation [have access to site analytics](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) ([here](https://superuser.com/site-analytics)). Let's confront your impression with some hard(-ish) data.

The screenshot below visualizes some statistics from the previous 100+ weeks (2 years).

[image: site analytics]

Based on the graphs one cannot tell if "the number of questions answered has dropped" or if "the number of questions that even get a comment has dropped"; or how dramatic the alleged drop was. The graphs simply do not contain this information.

Still the graphs contradict your general claim that "this website almost completely died" during the last 6 months or so.

Comment: If anything,  your first chart seems to show that fewer questions are going unanswered than before November.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I think it only shows the average number of answers per question has increased since. There still may be more questions going unanswered *if* some answered questions aggregate high number of answers.

Comment: Really Neat! Can you show a span for the last 3 years? And what exactly is 1w, 1v, and 1u? It also seems like the coronavirus might have dramatically increase activity on here.

Comment: eh. Its ok to leave the axis on.

Comment: does it go back a few more years? 06/18 to current for example?

Comment: @Sickest Covered 2 years.

Comment: @mokubai The assumption that people sat around watching TV for the last 3 months is nonsense. Most people I know, worked on projects they didn't have time for previously. I'm sure some of those projects were computer related. The spike in the last 3 months is clear to me... due to the "pandemic". Anyway it also seems like the 2019 was an interesting year. I'm not sure if "answers" is accepted answers or people just leaving answers. Seems like a huge drop off compared to 2018 and the start of 2020.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can anyone explain what occurs in December with the huge drop off every year? Everyone's on vacations or something??

Comment: Christmas break?